# Ruby: can't require installed gem 'stopwords-filter'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I'm trying to use this [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/stopwords-filter/versions/0.3.1), but even though it shows up with a `gem list` after I install it, a `require 'stopwords-filter'` in irb results in `LoadError: cannot load such file -- stopwords-filter`.

To make sure that I was actually able to install and use gems, I also tried installing [this](https://rubygems.org/gems/cool_ruby_faces/versions/0.0.9) gem and I can `require` it just fine. Everything works.

What am I missing about `stopwords-filter`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the gem is named `stopwords-filter`, the `require` statement is just `stopwords`:

```
require 'stopwords'
```

Comment: Sure enough. How would I go about checking the require statement?

Comment: If in Gemfile, `ls $(bundle show stopwords-filter)/lib/*.rb`

Comment: If the gem is on GitHub, you can take a look at the file name in the lib folder. In this case, the filename is 'stopwords.rb' from https://github.com/brenes/stopwords-filter/tree/master/lib